# "chances are" or "the chances are"?

Tags: articles, definite-article

Tell me please if have to include the definite article before the word *chance* in the following sentence.

> If you lose weight too quickly, then (**the**) chances are you are going to gain the weight back very soon.

If I need to include it, then tell me why please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a formal context, you would write "**the** chances are **that** you are going to gain the weight back". Articles and conjunctions are often omitted in informal speech and writing, especially with set phrases such as "[the] chances are [that]" *something will happen, is the case, etc.*.

[The case of the disappearing determiners](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=23277)

[Omission of that](https://www.englishgrammar.org/omission/)